# Using $this when not in object context with ReflectionFunction->invoke()

Tags: php, reflection, this, fatal-error

```
class someClass {
    private $success = "success\n";
    function getReflection() {
        return new ReflectionFunction(function() {
            print $this->success;
        });
     }
}
$reflection = (new someClass)->getReflection();
$reflection->invoke();
```

When I run this, I get a

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in Command line code on line 5
```

What's happening here? Why is `$this` not defined there...?

As I'm in a Closure inside a method, `$this` normally should be defined. And yes, I'm on a newer version than PHP 5.4.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReflectionFunction is operating on unbound Closures. That's why after the `ReflectionFunction::invoke()` call, there's no defined `$this` variable inside the Closure and as such your fatal error appears.

But there's a way around it.

ReflectionFunction offers you three necessary methods to call it with the `$this` binding:

- `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosure()`
- `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosureThis()`
- `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosureScopeClass()`

The `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosure()` is still unbound, but we can bind it via `Closure::bind()`.

All `Closure::bind()` needs is the Closure, the wished object to be bound to and the class scope.

Then the solution is:

```
call_user_func(\Closure::bind(
    $reflection->getClosure(),
    $reflection->getClosureThis(),
    $reflection->getClosureScopeClass()->name));
```

---

I initially wanted to post this as a question only, but I had found the solution myself just before posting, so just adding the answer. Context was this issue: https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn/pull/72

Comment: Just want to add this was a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66430) that got fixed in PHP 7.2.12+. The code in the original question works as of 7.2.12.